# Regex boundary to also exclude special characters

Tags: regex

I would like to make a regex to match a word, but don't match it if there are special characters on its sides.
I tried to use a word boundary (`\b`) on both sides but it doesn't seem to exclude special characters...

For example, this should work:
`text word-to-match more-text`

But this should not:
`text word-to-match-more-text`
Because there is a `-` between the word to match and more text.

What i have now is this:
`(?<=[^-\[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#])\bword-to-match\b(?=[^-\[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#])`

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way instead of using `[^-\[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#])` on both sides of the word.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use negative look-ahead?  `(?!...)` Also, negative look-behind `(?<!...)`

Comment: Such poorly written question is dupe for this well written problem? That question is about `Regex whitespace word boundary` and this one is `Regex boundary to also exclude special characters`. Dupe is not decided by similarity of answers unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use lookahead and lookbehind on both sides to fail the match if there is a non-whitespace character on either side:

```
(?<!\S)word-to-match(?!\S)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/94aqju/1)

- `(?<!\S)`: Fail if previous character is a non-whitespace
- `(?!\S)`: Fail if next character is a non-whitespace

Comment: Much more elegant than what i was using, this is pretty much what i was looking for, thank you!